# $_POST Crashes Site

Tags: php, html

I have the below php page, which is a holding page with a contact form:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!--<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">-->


    <title>Coming Soon</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- siimple style -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                    <h2 class="subtitle">We're working hard to improve our website and we'll be ready to launch soon
                    <h2 class="subtitle">Feel free to contact us below with any enquiries</h2>

                    <p>

                    <?php
                        $name = $_POST["contactname"];
                    ?>

                    <form class="Contact" method="post" action="">

                        <label class="alignleft">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" placeholder="Enter Name">

                        <label class="alignleft">Email</label>
                        <input name="Email" placeholder="Email Address">

                        <label class="alignleft">Enquiry</label>
                        <textarea name="Enquiry" placeholder="Your enquiry"></textarea><br>

                        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit!" class="btn btn-theme">

                    </form>

                <div class="social">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <!--<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Within the php section I am trying to read the values of the input boxes, however even with only

```
$_POST["contactname"];
```

the website returns a 500 Internal Server Error.  If i remove that line and replace with a simple:

```
echo "Test";
```

Then the site works and displays "Test"

If there something I am missing with the assigning of the variable from the input box?

Comment: You should turn on `error_reporting` and then read how the `POST` method works, because (most likely) there's no `POST` happening

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error you need to check the error log on the server for the reason. You probably have a syntax error somewhere.

Comment: Could you @Stuart1044 please accept or vote my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a second file to process the form instead of having it all on one page. Not only does it make your code look cleaner but I find it can also help with debugging. So it will look something like this:

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!--<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">-->


    <title>Coming Soon</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- siimple style -->
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                    <h2 class="subtitle">We're working hard to improve our website and we'll be ready to launch soon
                    <h2 class="subtitle">Feel free to contact us below with any enquiries</h2>

                    <form class="Contact" method="post" action="form_process.php">

                        <label class="alignleft">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" placeholder="Enter Name">

                        <label class="alignleft">Email</label>
                        <input name="Email" placeholder="Email Address">

                        <label class="alignleft">Enquiry</label>
                        <textarea name="Enquiry" placeholder="Your enquiry"></textarea><br>

                        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit!" class="btn btn-theme">

                    </form>

                <div class="social">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <!--<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>-->
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**form_process.php:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['contactname'])
    {
        $name = $_POST['contactname'];
        if(empty($name))
        {
            die("contact name is empty")
        }
        else
        {
            echo $name;
        }   
    }
    // Continue processing form data
?>
```

I would also follow the recommendations from other users about displaying PHP errors.

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure the key of the POST array is set and then validate your values first before you show them, and be sure to handle errors and invalid values!

```
   if(isset($_POST["contactname"])){
       // Do validation, like making sure its not a empty string
       if (!empty($_POST["contactname"])) {
           echo $_POST["contactname"];
       } else {
           echo "A validation error";
       }
    }
```

Also enable PHP error output which will greatly help you debug issues like this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And `display_errors = on` in your php.ini to make PHP show parse errors.

Comment: But how it helps with server 500 error ? if `$_POST["contactname"]` is `null` does it matter here `$name = $_POST["contactname"];` ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php  isset is special in that it checks if a variable has been set.  In PHP an array key that doesn't exist doesnt have a value of null, it just doesn't exist and will cause an error if you try to access it.

Comment: This won't fix a 500 error. Accessing an undefined variable just produces a warning, not a fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

You should validate it first

```
if(isset($_POST['contactname'])){
  // Do your post handling
}
```

Comment: Using an undefined index produces a warning, not a fatal 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

Firstable , you need to check if <kbd>$_POST</kbd> is defined , and not empty :

```
if(isset($_POST["contactname"]) && !empty($_POST["contactname"])){

echo $_POST["contactname"];
}
```

*Second* , i think you need to configure you'r server to show errors and not to redirect you to 500 error:
Just modify your <kbd>php.ini</kbd> with this line:

```
display_errors = on
```

Comment: exist() is not a function... I think you mean isset() or array_key_exists()

Comment: yes you are right, sorry i was thinking algorithmique

Comment: Using an undefined index just produces a warning, not a fatal error.

Comment: yes , that's why he should active the error reporting, or just by cheking the log